# div background color cuts off

Tags: html, css

Here is a screen shot of the what it looks like in IE6, works fine in everything else: http://i39.tinypic.com/2lcr4uw.png

It is within div class="article odd", which has overflow:auto; set.

Then it has a ul list (w/ clear:both; set), float to the left, w/ the li's split by 50%

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Best suggestion: don't develop for IE6, I know several companies who decided not to support IE6 anymore, and it goes well.

Comment: Itay is so right with this: To my mind IE6 doesn't deserve being supported. You can develop a website completely well after standards, working in every browser but not in that crappy piece of software.

Comment: Unless IE6 support is mandated by your company (and you can't change that mandate), it is best to drop support for IE6 and strongly encourage your users to move to IE8 or another browser. Continued support of this legacy and beyond buggy browser will only perpetuate IE6 and the devastation it has wreaked on progressive web development. DEATH TO IE6!!

Comment: I can't believe I'm seeing so many people saying to ignore IE6, I knew this was the sentiment in dev communities on reddit and digg, but I thought SO was more mature about that.  IE6 still has a significant market share.  Develop for your audience.  If you expect users to come to the site with IE6, make sure your site works in it.  "Don't develop for IE6" is a terrible suggestion and an easy-way-out for lazy developers.

Comment: 'Don't develop for IE6' is not a valid answer if your target audience has a large number of IE6 users. (Like, for instance, a Fortune 200 company that has more than 15000 users still on IE6).

Comment: And, no, I'm not happy about it. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Yup, this is a bug with using overflow:auto to contain floats.  If you add a width/height you'll fix that up.  For instance, width: 100%.

Here's a great page for information about this.
http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

Definately, don't use a "clearing div".  It adds unwanted markup and also has quirks with browser printing.

Edit: If that doesn't help, I think you'll need to give us some example code instead of a picture.

Comment: StackOverflow, YouTube and many other sites use clearing div/br's

Comment: Yeah, probably because they don't know the current way of fixing the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Hexxagonal, don't insert extra clearing div's. Better fixing it with CSS only.

I prefer giving IE6 `height: 1%;` or `zoom: 1;` which will trigger IE's hasLayout. This does the same for floats in IE as `overflow: hidden;` or `overflow: auto;` does for Firefox, Opera, Safari etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="article odd">
  <ul>
  </ul>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>

css
---
.clear
{
   clear: both;
}
```